# PHP Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

At initial stages of setting this up in a project.
I have enabled it the Google Developer page and trying to follow quickstart quide

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

however as with most Google API tutorials this 'quickstart' does not work.
I am taken through the authorization pages and given a code which I enter in the terminal but after a long time I am just given the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to read from stream in [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Stream.php

    Stack trace:
#0 [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php(382): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream->read()
    #1 [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php(214): GuzzleHttp\Psr7\copy_to_stream()
    #2 [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php(133): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->drain()
    #3 [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php(50): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->createResponse()
    #4 [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->__invoke()
    #5 [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(29): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke()
    #6 [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(70): GuzzleHtt in [site root]/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 52
```

No token.json file is created however the directory is writable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suspected the Google code is wrong.
Changing the scope on line 16 allows it to run correctly.

```
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly");
```

Full code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    //$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly");

    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```